# how to continue countdown timer while game is closed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanna make the reward countdown, I used this basic code for my countdown but that is not working on the background or when the game is closed, what should I do to continue working while the game is closed?

```
    float timeRemaining;
    public bool timerIsRunning; //  timeRemaining = Random.Range(15, 55);
    public Text timeText;

         void Update()
    {

        if (timerIsRunning)
        {
            if (timeRemaining > 0)
            {
                timeRemaining -= Time.deltaTime;
                DisplayTime(timeRemaining);
            }
            else
            {
                timeText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                OpenBoxButton.SetActive(true);
                Debug.Log("Time has run out!");
                timeRemaining = 0;
                timerIsRunning = false;                                        

            }
        }
       void DisplayTime(float timeToDisplay)
    {
        timeToDisplay += 1;

        float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay / 60);
        float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(timeToDisplay % 60);

        timeText.text = string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
    }
```

Comment: You don't. Just store the time, thats all you need to know the next time the game starts.

Comment: Yeah. Bascially KNOW when the next time is due, and use some simple read/compare to see whether the time is due.

Comment: so save the time and the amount to somewhere, and read it back

Comment: @tkausl how? with playerprefs?! I want to continue countdown even game is closed

Comment: thats you choice.. you might save it to a server we cant tell you how your game works

Comment: @BugFinder I want to save that locally, so you're mean is I should save with playerprefs and compare with delta.time?

Comment: you wouldnt compare with delta time as thats infinitesimally small.. You want to know how much was left on the time say 2.5h, and the time that was at.. and then take the time since that was saved and work out if any of your timer was left..

Comment: @BugFinder I little bit confused about that can you post that as an answer with DateTime.UtcNow or delta.time?

Comment: How is this question related to the UnityScript programming language?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure how you are confused - its the same process you do when you look at the clock at school and work and decide if its hometime yet..

You can either store when the timer should end (now + time left), or a duration left on the timer and when you last looked.

So, when you exit you have a timervalue - held in some form of units, lets go with seconds. float `countdown = 7200f`, aka 2 hours.

You know what time you quit the game, as `exittime = DateTime.UtcNow` and you saved that to "somewhere" you thought good.

So now you you're loading the game back in so, you have a `StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow`, the difference between when you exit and now, read in the time you saved and the countdown, and subtract it from the starttime, with `diff =  StartTime.Subtract(exittime)`, this returns the time difference.  You can then compare the difference to your countdown number. so if `diff.TotalSeconds >= countdown`, your timer ran out, else `countdown - diff.TotalSeconds` is the amount remaining.  Or if you saved the end time, totalseconds is either > 0 in which case you have that much time to go, or, 0 or less which means your timer ran out.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that compares countdown value with Utc time when the game open, how about continue working on the background(even game is close)? because I set notification and after finish countdown will be sent.

Comment: if your game isnt running nothing can happen its as simple as that, you might be able to program some form of notification timer on the OS, but if the game isnt running it cant do anything

Comment: I try to store countdown value with playerprefs and also Subtract exit time from start time but now I have another issue, how I can Subtract  playerprefs value from the difference (start time - exit time)

Comment: having showed all the code needed Im not sure how much more you can need..  you either stored the time the timer was going to end at, OR you stored the countdown and the time of exit.. both senarios are covered.. what did you do, which bit didnt you do..